# Cannot Read Properties of Null When Trying to Find the node.next.next for a Linked List

Tags: javascript, algorithm, linked-list, typeerror

### Description

I am trying to solve an algorithm problem which asks for the following:

> Given the head of a linked list, remove the nth node from the end of the list and return its head.

The function I've written accepts the linked list head and the nth node as arguments for the function.

```js
function removeNthFromEnd(head, n) { ... }
```

I decided to iterate through the list get the list length.

Then iterate through the list again and stop at the node before the nth node.

i.e. if n = 2 then I will stop at the 1st node.

### Issue

I have managed to stop at the correct node, I can access the next node. However I can't access the node after that.

I get the following type error:

```
Line 35 in solution.js
    console.log(node.next.next);
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'next')
```

### Code

Here's my code:

```js
function removeNthFromEnd(head, n) {
    // set the current node
    let node = head;
    // Set the current count
    let count = 1;

    // Loop through the linkedlist to get the length of the linked list
    while (node && node.next) {
        // Increment the count
        count++;
        // Move to the next node
        node = node.next;
    }

    // Set the current node to the head
    node = head;

    // Loop though the linked list to get the last node before the deleted node
    for (let i = 1; i < count - n; i++) {
        node = node.next;
    }

    node.next = node.next.next;

    return head;
};
```

### What I've tried

I've got it working using a variation of this algorithm but with one pass. I'm doing the same thing when I remove the node from the linked list (setting the next node to the next next node).

I'm assuming this is just some silly error. I just can't seem to see it.

Answer (score 1):

### Use a Dummy Node

I forgot to use a dummy node, for this exact reason.

I have a ListNode factory function with the following parameters for those who need it:

```js
function ListNode(val, next) {
     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
     this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
}
```

Here's the updated code:

```js
function removeNthFromEnd(head, n) {
    // dummy node
    const dummy = new ListNode(0);
    dummy.next = head;
    // set the current node
    let node = head;
    // Set the current count
    let count = 1;

    // Loop through the linkedlist to get the length of the linked list
    while (node && node.next) {
        // Increment the count
        count++;
        // Move to the next node
        node = node.next;
    }

    // Set the current node to the head
    node = dummy;

    // Loop though the linked list to get the last node before the deleted node
    for (let i = 0; i < count - n; i++) {
        node = node.next;
    }

    // Set the next node of the node before the nth node to the node after the nth node
    node.next = node.next.next;

    return dummy.next;
}
```